# Redirect interface method calls

Tags: java, interface

I have an `Interface1` and two Implementations of it, `ClassA` and `ClassB`. I want to redirect all method calls from ClassA to ClassB.  Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
class ClassA implements Interface1{
    method1(){
       b.method1();
    }
    method2(){
        b.method2();
    }
    method3(){
        b.method3();
    }
    //and so on...
}
```

Is there an more easy way to do this?

Comment: You could use a dynamic proxy (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), but without knowing why you're doing this, it's hard to tell if it's the best solution or not. What's the actual point of ClassA, if it doesn't do anything other than delegating to another class having the same interface?

Comment: Class A should have a purpose to exist.. May be you should have a look at decorator pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an [abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) instead of an interface? You can put your common implementations in the abstract class, and in `ClassA` and `ClassB` only implement the methods where the two classes differ.

```
abstract class Abstract {
    void method1() {
        //do stuff...
    }
    abstract void method2();
}

class ClassA extends Abstract {
    @override
    void method2() {
        // do something...
    }
}

class ClassB extends Abstract {
    @override
    void method2() {
        // do something else...
    }
}
```